# Backbone model.fetch not setting values

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sequelize.js

Here is my backbone model constructor

```
define([], function(){
     return Backbone.Model.extend({

         urlRoot:'/dummy-api/Instances',
         defaults:{
             name:null,
             read:false,
             write:false
         },

         initialize: function () {
             this.fetch();
             console.log("after init "+this.get("id")+" name="+this.get("name"));
         }

     })
});
```

and at /dummy-api/Instances/1 is have put this

```
{"id":1,"name":"bangladesh"}
```

And I have attached this model to a view with this

```
define(['models/instance.js'], function(Model){
     View = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function() {
            this.model = new Model({
                id:1
            });

        });
     return new View();
});
```

The URL is getting called, and it's content is as above, I can see that in firebug, but "name" isnt getting set.
I know I can provide a parse function, which as I am using sequelize-restful-extended I may need to do, but I'd first like backbone to read and set from a fixed file. The doco is straight forward enough, what I have should work, so am I doing something else bad ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're logging the values before the model.fetch has completed.

Set a callback instead to log the values after fetch has successfully completed, and it should work as expected.

```
define([], function(){
    return Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot:'/dummy-api/Instances',
        defaults:{
            name:null,
            read:false,
            write:false
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this.fetch({
               success: function() {
                   console.log("after init "+this.get("id")+" name="+this.get("name"));
               }.bind(this)
            });
        }
    })
});
```

This is necessary because `this.fetch()` executes an XMLHttpRequest asynchronously, and continues on to the next line of code while that request is executed by your browser in a separate "thread" (for all intents and purposes).

Comment: I then added this to my view and it rendered correctly             this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);

Comment: Instead of doing a manual render after fetch call, you can use model binder(https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder). Or if you are displaying a list, use a collection and composite view, which re-renders itself on collection change.